# What does an asterisk in empty parentheses mean?

Tags: c

What does this c code do?

```
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

Especially I confused about subj.

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is _subj_?

Comment: [cast `code` to pointer to function-returning-`int`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28int+%28*%29%28%29%29code).

Comment: @WhozCraig "Bad Request" when opening your link

Comment: @lucidbrot no clue what happened to that link. cdecl.org is normally what I use now anyway, though. [see here](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*f%29%28%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to do a typecast, we use the following:

```
(type_to_cast) value;
```

when you want to cast some `value` to a certain `type`.

Also remember you define a function pointer as

```
return_type (*pointer_name) (data_types_of_parameters);
```

And the type of a function pointer is

```
return_type (*) (data_types_of_parameters)
```

Finally, you can call a function with its pointer as

```
(*func_pointer)(arguments);
```

So, with those 4 points in mind, you see that your C code:

**First** defines a funciton pointer `func`.

**Second**, casts `code` as a function pointer and assign its value to `func`

**Third**, calls the function pointed by `func`, and casts the value reutrned to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

It's a cast to a function pointer.

The sequence `int (*)()` is for a function pointer that takes an indeterminate number of arguments, and returns an `int`. Wrapping it in parentheses like `(int (*)())`, when combined with an expression, is casting the result of the expression.

The code you present, with comments:

```
// Declare a variable `func` which is a pointer to a function
int (*func)();

// Cast the result of the expression `code` and assign it to the variable `func`
func = (int (*)()) code;

// Use the variable `func` to call the code, cast the result to `int` (redundant)
// The returned value is also discarded
(int)(*func)();
```

Comment: This function call will discard the return value.

Answer (score 0):

- `int (*func)();` declares `func` as a pointer to a function that takes any number of parameters and and return `int`.
- In statement `func = (int (*)()) code;`, a cast is applied to `code` and then assign it to the function pointer `func`.
- `(int)(*func)();` doesn't make much sense. Cast is not needed and it discards the return value. The call should be simply like

  ```
  int var = func();
  ```

  or

  ```
  int var = (*func)();
  ```